# How do I express the integral of $\tan^{2n}(x)$ using sigma notation?

Tags: integration, summation

How do I express the integral of $\tan^{2n}(x)$  with respect to $x$ using sigma notation?

$$\int \tan^{2n}(x)\, dx = \text{???}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the reduction formula,

$$\int\tan^{2n}{x}\,dx=\int\tan^{2n-2}{x}\left(\sec^2{x}-1\right)\,dx\\
=\int\tan^{2n-2}{x}\,\sec^2{x}\,dx-\int\tan^{2n-2}{x}\,dx\\
=\frac{1}{2n-1}\tan^{2n-1}{x}-\int\tan^{2n-2}{x}\,dx$$